# Desktop ArcGIS Region Group outcome interpretation

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, classification

I am new to GIS and I sincerely cannot explain some results.

I have been trying to run the Region Group tool on an unsupervised classification output with 23 classes that looks like this:

[image]

The tool used is as follows:

[image]

and the outcome is finally as follows:

[image]

Could anyone please explain why is the outcome like this?

Comment: It shows that you have 104817 groups of connected cells. What is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank you @FelixIP . I was hoping to clear out a bit more my classes in the classified raster.
What i meant by an explanation of the outcome was mainly why it appears like that: top to bottom in a linear value increment, and not like the outcome i was expecting as i understood from the documentation: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/region-group.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems i found my answer when reading more carefully the documentation ([Region Group](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/region-group.htm)):

In the "Usage part" it is stated that

> Usage
>
> The first region scanned receives the value one, the second two, and
>   so forth, until all regions are assigned a value. **The scan moves from
>   left to right, top to bottom.** The values assigned to the output zones
>   are based on when they are encountered in the scanning process.

**The scan moves from left to right, top to bottom.** : Explaining the raster that i was inspecting